# Cause of PostgreSQL foreign key violation?

Tags: postgresql, foreign-keys, postgresql-9.2, corruption

My PostgreSQL (9.2) database contains two tables `registrations` and `attributes` with a foreign key constraint:

```
postgres=# \d+ registrations;
                Table "public.registrations"
 Column  | Type  | Modifiers | Storage  | Stats target | Description
---------+-------+-----------+----------+--------------+-------------
 name    | text  | not null  | extended |              |
 parent  | text  |           | extended |              |
 storage | bytea |           | extended |              |
Indexes:
    "registrations_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (name)
Referenced by:
    TABLE "attributes" CONSTRAINT "attributes_cname_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (cname) REFERENCES registrations(name) ON DELETE CASCADE
Has OIDs: no

postgres=# \d+ attributes;
                 Table "public.attributes"
 Column | Type  | Modifiers | Storage  | Stats target | Description
--------+-------+-----------+----------+--------------+-------------
 cname  | text  | not null  | extended |              |
 aname  | text  | not null  | extended |              |
 tags   | text  |           | extended |              |
 value  | bytea |           | extended |              |
Indexes:
    "attributes_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (cname, aname)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "attributes_cname_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (cname) REFERENCES registrations(name) ON DELETE CASCADE
Has OIDs: no
```

At some point I realised that some rows violated the foreign key constraint:

```
postgres=# SELECT COUNT(*) FROM attributes LEFT JOIN registrations ON attributes.cname=registrations.name WHERE registrations.name IS NULL;
 count
-------
    71
(1 row)
```

Could you help me understand how this corruption could happen?

Comment: X-posted to http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/111655/7788

Comment: @CraigRinger X-post deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A constraint marked as `NOT VALID` is the one case you might expect to see violations, but the `NOT VALID` clause would show up in the psql `\d+` output. (I believe it's possible to manually update this flag in the catalog, but I hope for your sake that this isn't the issue...)

As far as I know, the only supported way of bypassing a foreign key check is to `SET session_replication_role TO replica` before modifying the data. This is there for the benefit of replication processes, operating under the assumption that the constraint has already been validated on the master - though this can certainly go wrong if your replicator is buggy or misconfigured.

It's also possible for a superuser to manually disable the constraint's underlying triggers (and it's often tempting for someone trying to speed up a bulk import). The following will tell you if the triggers are currently active (`tgenabled` should be `'O'`):

```
SELECT *
FROM pg_trigger
WHERE tgname ~ '^RI_ConstraintTrigger'
  AND tgrelid IN ('registrations'::regclass, 'attributes'::regclass)
```

I don't think there's any way of knowing whether this was temporarily changed in the past, though if you have statement logging enabled, you might find an `ALTER TABLE ... DISABLE TRIGGER` statement in there somewhere.

There is also [at least one loophole](http://postgresql.nabble.com/BUG-13572-Foreign-Key-Corruption-td5862207.html) in the foreign key enforcement, and of course, it's always possible that you've found a bug...

Comment: Our system actually involves a replication between 2 databases, do you think that could be the cause of the issue?

Comment: @fiddler: Assuming you're using some kind of trigger-based replication, rather than Postgres' binary replication modes, then it's not out of the question. Though presumably the replication process would never be writing to the master, so the data would only be wrong on the slave.

Comment: Well, we use the binary replication (streaming replication)

Comment: OK, streaming replication will never have this issue

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if the FK contraint was created with a `NOT VALID` clause (don't do this):

```
CREATE TABLE one
        ( one_id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
        );

CREATE TABLE two
        ( two_id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
        , one_id INTEGER NOT NULL
        );

INSERT INTO one(one_id)
SELECT gs FROM generate_series(0,12,2) gs;

INSERT INTO two(two_id,one_id)
SELECT gs, gs FROM generate_series(0,12,3) gs;

ALTER TABLE two
        ADD CONSTRAINT omg FOREIGN KEY (one_id) references one(one_id)
        -- DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
        NOT VALID
        ;
```

Comment: Is there any command to check if this constraint was created with this clause?

Comment: Don't know. Maybe check the logs, if any? Note: pg_dump emits the `NOT VALID` phrase, too, so it must be in the catalogs somewhere.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be the case, I see the following in the logs: `create table attributes (cname text not null, aname text not null, tags text, value bytea, primary key (cname, aname), foreign key (cname) references registrations (name) on delete cascade)`